# Why do English people pronounce 'sixth' as 'sicth'?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, north-american-english, transatlantic-differences, hiberno-english

It's common practice in Ireland (and the US as far as I know) to pronounce the x in the middle of sixth: six-th *[sɪksθ]*. However, I've noticed from visits to England as well as watching British television, that a lot of English people pronounce it as 'sicth' *[sɪkθ]*. Why is this, and is it an accepted usage?

Comment: Yes, it's accepted usage. Also common among non- newscasters and actors in AmE.

Comment: This isn't the 'th' sound though. It's 'k' or 'ks'?

Comment: Ronan Murphy, it's not always pronounced as *sikth*, in the UK. There are British people who pronounce it as *siksth*.

Comment: @Tristanr I'd imagine there are many who pronounce it the original way alright. I'm just wondering why the other came about.

Comment: Other discussions of this phenomenon [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/142201/15299) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/110234/15299).

Comment: Ronan Murphy, that's probably because it can be difficult to pronounce, especially for people who like to speak in a hurry.

Comment: Even us fast speakers from the US (Chicago-area) pronounce it correctly as siksth.  (as a personal aside...I find it fascinating that people from so far away can make assumptions about people with whom they don't actually interact frequently enough to make the assumption.)

Comment: I've replied to this specific question here where I give examples of English people saying sicth etc: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144927/is-the-th-sound-usually-reduced-in-spoken-english/311506#311506

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, the usual Irish-English pronunciation of “sixth” is [sɪkst] with the famous shift of [θ] to [t]. In England this word is pronounced as [sɪksθ], but I can imagine that some speakers of Irish English might have difficulty distinguishing [sθ] from [θ], as these sounds do not occur in their own dialect.

Comment: I think the OP states the opposite - in Ireland he observes the pronunciation [sɪksθ], and during his visits to England he heard a lot of [sɪkθ], and thus wonders if this is widely acceptable.

Comment: This is correct. [sɪksθ] is how I pronounce it myself.

Comment: Here is what I guess is happening: The word *sixth* ends with a consonant cluster which is quite difficult to pronounce, so lots of people simplify it. In Ireland, if [sɪksθ] is simplified, it gets simplified to [sɪkst] (which the OP doesn't notice because he's used to it).  In England, it gets simplified to [sɪkθ], which the OP notices because it's unusual for him.

Comment: @Peter: In US movies I've always noticed many (Afro-) Americans pronouncing ***ask*** as ***aks***. But lately I keep hearing that reduced to (even simpler?) ***ats***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the South Wales accent also pronounces **ask** as "aks."

Comment: @Greybeard: I'm in Sussex, but I had a girlfriend in Cardiff for 15 years, so I spent quite a bit of time listening to people from South Wales over the years. I don't recall ever hearing ***aks*** instead of ***ask*** - except from one woman who'd originally come from the West Indies anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My Welsh girlfriend was from Swansea...

Comment: @Greybeard: And she says ***aks***? Is she a native Anglophone?

Comment: Yes. She is a retired teacher. It is not the same as the West Indian aks, which seems to have a longish "a" - this was a short vowel.